# Get value based on key using HashMap in nested repeat controls

Tags: xpages-ssjs

On a custom control I'm using a HashMap (loaded in the cc's beforePageLoad event) to pass data into a nested repeat control but I can't figure out how to get a specific value from the map.  (I'm a longtime Notes dev but an Xpages/Java noobie.)

I'm simulating a Notes categorized view but I have to use derived data, not a view. The format of the data is (all strings):

```
key         data
---         ----
category1   name1^nextDueDate1^lastCompletedDate1
category2   name2^nextDueDate2^lastCompletedDate2
category3   name3^nextDueDate3^lastCompletedDate3
```

I pass the categories separately as a simple array to the outer repeat via **viewScope.categoryArray** and I pass the map in **viewScope.catDataMap**. A button within the outer repeat displays/hides a sub panel containing the nested repeat. For testing, I'm trying to display the corresponding data string (e.g., name1^nextDueDate1^lastCompletedDate1) in the very last computed text field (id=showValue) based on the category (e.g., category1):

```
<xp:panel id="panelRepeat">
  <xp:repeat id="repeatCategory" value="#{viewScope.categoryArray}" var="category">
    <xp:button value="#{javascript:category}">
      <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="panelRepeat">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.categoryDisplay = category}]]></xp:this.action>
      </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>

    <xp:panel id="panelData" rendered="#{javascript:@IsMember(category, viewScope.categoryDisplay)}">
      <xp:repeat id="repeatDocData" var="catData">
        <xp:this.value>
          <![CDATA[#{javascript:var map:java.util.HashMap = viewScope.catDataMap;
            return map.entrySet()}]]>
        </xp:this.value>

        <xp:text id="showValue" escape="true" value="#{javascript:catData.???????}" />

      </xp:repeat>
    </xp:panel>

  </xp:repeat>
</xp:panel>
```

(Note that I left out a bunch of extra stuff in my example, like when panelData is hidden, etc.) After failing to get the data by trying to access **map** directly, I found a [post](http://oliverbusse.notesx.net/Privat/osnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?documentId=EB17DF835CCE2F5CC1257C1C0074C823) that said you have to use **map.entrySet()** instead. However, I looked through the Java documentation for both [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet()) and [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) and just can't figure out what method to use. All I want is the LS equivalent of

```
Dim catData as String
catData = catDataMap("category1")
print catData    'name1^nextDueDate1^lastCompletedDate1
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction or propose an alternative solution? (Can I do this more simply in Javascript?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are returning the wrong thing for the value in the nested repeat control. Rather than `return map.entrySet();` you should use return `map.get(category);` which should return the string of values that you can then parse.

Comment: Thanks! I eventually arrived at the same conclusion but you confirmed it.  I think the post I read about needing to use entrySet sent me in the wrong direction--I should have tested for myself.  I really need to learn more Java but it's daunting...

Comment: The reality is that this is really just JavaScript, which is simpler than Java. You might also benefit from the concept that your map can contain maps like this:
viewScope.catDataMap = [{name:"name1", dueDate:"duedate1", completedDate:"completedDate1"}, {name:"name2", dueDate:"duedate2", completedDate:"completedDate2"}, {name:"name3", dueDate:"duedate3", completedDate:"completedDate3"}]